# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules

I've changed my friends.js code from:

`var friendDb = require('database/friends');`

to

`var friendDb = require('../database/friends');`

And I've even tried explicitly calling `friends` as `friends.json`

But no matter what I do, I have no friends...

```
Error: Cannot find module '../database/friends'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/seanwilliamson/Desktop/streamcolor-v2.0/app/models/friends.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

In all seriousness, here's the relevant app structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── friends.js
│   │   └── responseGenerator.js

├── database
│   └── friends.json
```

The bottom comment from Chopper Lee of this stack post:
[Cannot find module in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446514/cannot-find-module-in-nodejs) mentioned something about "[setting] the system value : NODE_PATH; it should point to your global module location;"

So I tried that... and I have a whole separate post for the potential problem I'm having there but I'm not sure if it's related: [echo $NODE_PATH returns two global installation paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596623/echo-node-path-returns-two-global-installation-paths/32596711#32596711) (basically, I *think* I have two installation paths for my global modules whenever I run `npm install -g [foo-module]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be:

```
var friendDb = require('../../database/friends');
```

Comment: You deserve all the upvotes. I had no clue you could stack **..** like that